# Second Highest Salary without subquery

Tags: sql

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName    Department      Salary   
----------- --------------- --------------- ---------
1           Nisha           Finance         40000.00
2           John            Finance         25000.00
3           NEo             Finance         25000.00
4           Dan             Finance         15000.00
5           Jstin           IT              80000.00
6           Amy             IT              50000.00
```

I want to get the second highest Salary which is 50000.00 without using subquery?

Comment: What SQL database? This is one of the things where it's very different depending on what kind of database you use and maybe even what version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `limit` and `offset` (to skip highest salary)
In MySQL

```
select * from table order by Salary desc limit 1 offset 1
```

In SQL server

```
select * from table order by Salary desc offset 1 rows fetch next 1 row only
```

You can try with another Database here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15c32/1/0

Answer (score 5):

Try below query, it will work.

```
select max(e1.salary) from Employee e1,Employee e2 where e1.salary<e2.salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use LIMIT 1,1 (grab first result after first row). I come from the MySql side of things so the sql might have to be adjusted slightly for Sql Server.

```
SELECT Salary FROM table ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT Salary
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY Salary DESC OFFSET 1 ROWS

FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY

Answer (score 0):

With Query Limit

```
select * from Employee order by Salary desc limit(1,1)
```

With Subquery, you can find Nth Max Salary

```
SELECT id, salary  FROM Employee e 
WHERE 2= (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) FROM Employee p WHERE e.salary <=p.salary);
```

Answer (score -1):

Test this query after adding your table name and column names

```
select MAX(country) as country from users where country < ( select MAX(country) as country from users where country < (SELECT MAX(country) from users ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use TOP keyword to fetch number of records from the database tables. for example

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE NAME
```